# Qual a maneira correta de usar o flush(); e sleep(); em um foreach?

Tags: php, wordpress

Fiz uma página em php para gerar um relatório de vendas no formato .csv através do WooCommerce no sistema WordPress.

```
<?php 
//incluir as funções principais do WordPress
require("/home/site/public_html/wp-blog-header.php");
require_once("/home/site/public_html/wp-config.php");
require_once("/home/site/public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php");
?>

<?php
$order_statuses = array( 'wc-completed');

$customer_orders = wc_get_orders( array (
    'date_completed' => '2020-09-14...2020-09-15',
    'meta_key' => '_customer_user',
    'post_status' => $order_statuses,
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'numberposts' => -1,
) );
$myfile1 = fopen("/home/site/public_html/shop/report/2020.csv", "w") or die("Erro ao abrir relatório!<br>");
fwrite($myfile1, "\"Data\",\"Pedido\",\"Item\",\"Categoria\",\"Quant.\",\"Valor\",\"Pagamento\",\"Usuário\"\r");
echo '<table><tbody>
        <tr>
            <th><strong>Data</strong></th>
            <th><strong>Pedido</strong></th>
            <th><strong>Item</strong></th>
            <th><strong>Categoria</strong></th>
            <th><strong>Quant.</strong></th>
            <th><strong>Valor</strong></th>
            <th><strong>Pagamento</strong></th>
            <th><strong>Usuário</strong></th>
            </tr>';

foreach($customer_orders as $order ){

    $order_id = method_exists( $order, 'get_id' ) ? $order->get_id() : $order->id;

    foreach($order->get_items() as $item_id => $item){

    $product_id = method_exists( $item, 'get_product_id' ) ? $item->get_product_id() : $item['product_id'];

    if( method_exists( $item, 'get_data' ) ) {
         $item_data = $item->get_data();
         $pedido = $item_data['order_id'];
         $item_name = $item->get_name();
         $produto = $item_data['product_id'];
         $quantity = $item_data['quantity'];
         $total = $item_data['total'];
         $total=str_replace(".", ",", $total);
         $pgto=$order->payment_method_title;
         $order_date_modified=$order->date_completed;
         $data=date_format($order_date_modified, "d/m/Y H:i:s");
         $userid=$order->customer_user;
         $user_info = get_userdata($order->user_id);
         $usuario = $user_info->user_login;
         //$email=$order->billing_email;
    } else {
         $total = wc_get_order_item_meta( $item_id, '_line_total', true );
    }

        foreach( wp_get_post_terms( $produto, 'product_cat' ) as $term ){
            if( $term ){
                $categoria = $term->name;
            }
        }
        
        echo '<tr><td>'.$data.'</td>';
        echo '<td>#'.$pedido.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$item_name.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$categoria.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$quantity.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$total.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$pgto.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$usuario.'</td>';
        
        fwrite($myfile1,"\"$data\",\"$pedido\",\"$item_name\",\"$categoria\",\"$quantity\",\"$total\",\"$pgto\",\"$usuario\"\r");
        
        flush();
        sleep(1);
    
    }
}

fclose($myfile1);
echo '</tbody></table>';
?>
```

Adicionei o *flush();* e *sleep(1);* após a gravação de cada linha no arquivo .csv, pois desejo que a tabela seja criada na página do navegador, conforme acontece no exemplo abaixo. onde uma linha aparece a cada segundo:

```
<?php

    for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++){
        echo 'processing...<br>';
        flush();
        sleep(1);
    }
?>
```

Porém a página que criei processa todas as informações de uma só vez e não aos poucos como esperado.

Estou buscando alternativas para gravar os dados sem receber um erro de *timeout*, pois quando executamos o script para puxar todos os pedidos deste ano o processo é simplesmente interrompido, algumas vezes mostra uma mensagem de timeout no navegador, mas não gera nenhum log de erro.

Comment: Como dá erro de timeout se o processo é interrompido sem erro?

Comment: @Woss me expliquei mal no último paragrafo, algumas vezes mostra uma mensagem de timeout no navegador, mas não gera nenhum log de erro.

Comment: Qual é o tempo máximo para dar timeout que está configurado no servidor?

Comment: @Woss no php.ini está como 'max_execution_time = 5000000', mesmo assim a mensagem "Request Timeout" aparece após 2 minutos de execução

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em teoria seu script poderia funcionar, mas no manual php explica que muitos servidores não realizam o envio da página até que todo o script tenha sido concluído, mesmo você guardando em buffer parte do código.

A explicação está neste link:
[manual flush](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.flush.php)

Uma solução para isto seria utilizar ajax para ir carregando partes da tela a cada segundo, ou carregar toda a tela com a maior parte oculta e ir exibindo com javascript (display:none => display:block) aos poucos. Particularmente eu escolheria a segunda opção.

Comment: Li alguns artigos para aprender como utilizar o ajax, mas não consegui entender como funcionava e não consegui aplicar no meu script atual. Sobre ir mostrando aos poucos o resultado na tela, nem é importante, no final acabarei trabalhando só com o arquivo .csv criado. Continuarei buscando mais informações sobre ajax pra tentar aplicar aqui, obrigado desde já.

Comment: o que ajuda bastante é a biblioteca jquery que facilita bastante o trabalho com ajax

Comment: obrigado pelas informações, ainda não consegui algo 100%, no servidor tem algo interrompendo a execução da página com 120 segundos apenas quando incluo os arquivos de configuração do wordpress

Comment: se continua usando o flush para despejar buffer a cada 1 segundo você acaba atingindo o limite de tempo de execução da página.
Você pode usar a função set_time_limit() para modificar o tempo, mas ainda não acho que esta seja a melhor solução. O ideal é verificar de tempos em tempos com o ajax e usar appped() do javascript para adicionar os campos novos