# Alguém sabe dizer como usar a função flush(); do php em um site WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Há algum tempo postei [esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/472458/33945) pois precisava rodar um script que puxava muitas informações (vários pedidos) no WordPress, pesquisando um pouco encontrei a função *flush();* para poder ir liberando o conteúdo aos poucos conforme o script fosse rodando.

O exemplo encontrado funciona perfeitamente se você utilizar ele em uma página fora do WordPress (mesmo que dentro do mesmo servidor).

```
<?php

    for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++){
        echo 'processing...<br>';
        flush();
        sleep(1);
    }
?>
```

Realizando alguns testes, percebi que o mesmo script acima não funciona se for executado em uma página do WordPress, por exemplo:

```
function simple_function_2() {
    
    for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++){
        echo 'processing...<br>';
        flush();
        sleep(1);
    }
}

add_shortcode( 'own_shortcode2', 'simple_function_2' );
```

Como exemplificado [nesta pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61901998/5429657), a função deve ser adicionada ao arquivo *functions.php* e chamada em uma página do WordPress com:

> [own_shortcode2]

Por algum motivo, a página terá a saída esperada:

```
processing...
processing...
processing...
processing...
processing...
processing...
processing...
processing...
processing...
processing...
```

Mas cada uma das palavras "processing..." não é exibida a cada segundo, assim como acontece quando o comando é chamado em uma página fora do WordPress. Se você tentar executa-lo, verá que a página em si demora 10 segundos para concluir o carregamento, e só então é exibida ao usuário.

Tentei encontrar algo na internet relatando o problema, mas não consegui chegar a lugar algum.

Existe alguma alternativa para poder rodar o *flush();* em um site WordPress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer a seguinte modificação no código:

```
function simple_function_2() {
    
    for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++){
        flush();
        echo str_pad("processing...<br>", 4096);
        sleep(1);
    }
}

add_shortcode( 'own_shortcode2', 'simple_function_2' );
```

Explicando o `echo str_pad("processing...<br>", 4096);`

- Alguns navegadores não exibirão o conteúdo se for muito curto
- Usamos `str_pad()` para tornar a saída longa o suficiente
  Assim você vai conseguir ver a execução linha a linha na tela.

Obs: Caso seu tema Worpress tenha algun tipo de preloader, você vai precisar desabilitar!

Obs2: testei e funciona.

Fonte: [PHP flush() Function](https://www.w3schools.com/php/ref_output_flush.asp)

Comment: muito obrigado, funcionou :D